# Placing DIV in form, can't set minimum width and height

Tags: html, css

I have the following html snippet:

```html
<form name="foo">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Legend Here</legend>
    <label for="the_date">Date: </label><input type="text" name="the_date" id="the_date">
    <select class="show_when_needed" id="event_state">
      <option value="-1" selected="selected">N/A</option>
      <option value="1">One</option>
      <option value="2">Two</option>
      <option value="3">Three</option>
      <option value="4">Four</option>
      <option value="5">Five</option>
      <option value="6">Six</option>         
    </select>
    <div class="foobar" style="display: inline; border: 1px black; min-width: 20px; min-height: 15px; background: blue;"></div>
    <button type="button" name="go_next" id="go_next">Go!</button>
  </fieldset>
  <hr />
  <button type="button" id="save_object">Save Object</button>
</form>
```

I am trying to have the div show inline, and set a minimum width (to force it to show on screen).

The HTML above is not achieving that goal. How do I correct it so that the div appears alongside the select option control?

**[[Additional Info]]**

I have tried this on the latest versions of FF and Chrome - both fail to display correctly.

Comment: You didn't post the most important part – styles.

Comment: @dfsq: look again. I have inlined my style definitions...

Comment: You cant set a width on an inline element.

Comment: A [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) would probably be helpful. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the element a `display: inline-block`, you can't set width or height of an inline element because it behaves just like a `<span>` or a `<strong>` would, taking only the space it needs.

[Take a look at this updated snippet with `display: inline-block`](http://codepen.io/fabiosang/pen/VpMRNb)

Answer (score 0):

change from `display: inline;` to `display: block;`.

```html
<form name="foo">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Legend Here</legend>
        <label for="the_date">Date: </label><input type="text" name="the_date" id="the_date">
        <select class="show_when_needed" id="event_state">
            <option value="-1" selected="selected">N/A</option>
            <option value="1">One</option>
            <option value="2">Two</option>
            <option value="3">Three</option>
            <option value="4">Four</option>
            <option value="5">Five</option>
            <option value="6">Six</option>                                  
        </select>
        <div class="foobar" style="display: block; border: 1px black; min-width: 20px; min-height: 15px; background: blue;"></div>
        <button type="button" name="go_next" id="go_next">Go!</button>
    </fieldset>
    <hr />
    <button type="button" id="save_object">Save Object</button>     
</form>
```